# Column-Width and Image Wrapping in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Using the CSS3 `column-width` property in Firefox seems to not work as expected. When an image that is taller than it's container exists, the image does not wrap onto a new column as expected:

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj7wS/1/)

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x600" alt="" />
</div>
```

and

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 300px;
    -moz-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
}
```

One would expect two columns with the top half on the left followed by the bottom half of the image. This works as expected on Chrome, however with Firefox, it seems to simply overflow. Is there an additional CSS style that needs to be applied in this case, or is this something that is broken/not implemented in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a reported [bug in Webkit's CSS renderer](https://bugs.webkit.org/show%5Fbug.cgi?id=25633). Firefox and Opera behave as expected.

The only way to get Webkit to render it right, would be to set the max-height of images to the height of the container:

```
#container > img {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ebtq/)

I guess not the expected answer, but maybe still helpful.